# Leaflet TimeDimension show local time

Tags: javascript, html, time, leaflet

Is there a way to not display UTC time, only display local time?
Because of the time difference, the UTC time is a bit strange.

I refer to this [website](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension#lcontroltimedimension).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the time section the UTC time change to local time and visa versa. You can set the default to Local time, if you add `timeZones: ["Local", "UTC"]` and change the sequence from the timeZones array (https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension#ltimedimensionplayer)

```
const timeDimensionControl = L.control.timeDimension({
    loopButton: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    timeZones: ["Local", "UTC"]
});
```